# NHibernate: Many-to-One - *Must* You Load the Parent Object?

Tags: nhibernate, loading, internals, object-persistence

Assume the following entity classes:

```
public class Player
{
 public virtual int ID { get; set; }
 public virtual string Name { get; set; }
 public virtual Team Team { get; set; }
}

public class Team
{
 public virtual int ID { get; set; }
 public virtual string City { get; set; }
 public virtual string Nickname { get; set; }
}
```

Assume the following mapping class for Player:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" default-lazy="false">
 <class name="Player">
  <id name="ID" column="ID" type="System.Int32" unsaved-value="null">
   <generator class="native"/>
  </id>
  <property name="Name" column="Name" not-null="true" type="System.String"  length="50" insert="true" update="true"/>
  <many-to-one name="Team" not-null="true" outer-join="auto" insert="true" update="true">
   <column name="TeamID"/>
  </many-to-one>
 </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And assume the following Player repository method:

```
public void Add(Player player)
{
 using (ISession session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
 {
  using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
  {
   session.Save(player);
   transaction.Commit();
  }
 }
}
```

**My question:**

Must I load a full-fledged Team (parent object) when I want to create a new Player?
Or can I specify a "mock" object, and only specify the foreign key?

```
Player player = new Player
              {
               Name = "Tom Brady",
               Team = new TeamRepository().GetTeamByCityAndNickname("New England", "Patriots") // Is this the only way?
               // or can I do this?
               // Team = new Team { ID = 22 }
              };
new PlayerRepository().Add(player);
```

---

- And if I can't specify a "mock"
  object (specifying only the
  foreign key), can you please explain
  why I can't?
- That is, can you please give me an idea about what's going on under the hood?

---

Heads-up:

- A fellow had [nearly the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101021/nhibernate-many-to-one-problem).
- Here's [the answer that made the most sense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101021/nhibernate-many-to-one-problem/2105992#2105992).

---

- Interestingly, when speaking about EF
  4.0 during a [DotNetRocks episode](http://www.dotnetrocks.com/default.aspx?showNum=514), Julia Lerman
  acknowledged that many people want to
  use the foreign key in these types of
  situations.

---

**EDIT:** [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/608947/hibernate-difference-between-session-get-and-session-load/608994#608994) points to the essence of my question.

> Think of it like having an object that
>   only keeps the Id and that will load
>   the rest if you ever need it. If
>   you're just passing it arround to
>   create relationships (like FKs), the
>   id is all you'll ever need.

- Well if that's the case, then why do I need to be worried about proxy objects and such? Why can't I just create a "dummy" object and specify the foreign key value if that's all that really matters?

Comment: I was using the so called dummy object before I knew about Load. It does indeed work...but it's not advised. So you want to know why it's not advised? that's a good question.

Comment: @dotjoe: Sounds like we're in the same camp. :) // Suffice it to say, I never received a formal 'NHibernate Best Practices' education (probably most, if not all of us fall into this camp). But regardless, I'd like to open this black box a little and understand the 'why' behind the recommended best practices.

Comment: haha me neither...I just followed that whack beginner's sample project from the NHibernate website. Then I started checking out questions on SO and following Ayende's blog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have access to Session at this point you can call

```
Team = Session.Load<Team>(id);
```

The premise of Load is that it will create an NHibernate proxy that can resolve itself if needed. Of course you have to be sure the id exists or you will get an EntityNotFound error if it ever tries to resolve itself.

Answer (score 4):

you use the foreign key like so...

```
Team = session.Load<Team>(id);
```

know the [difference between load and get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/608947/hibernate-difference-between-session-get-and-session-load)

Comment: Yes - I understand that this is the convention, but I'm wondering if this is the *only* way; and if so, I'd like to know why.

Comment: I answered a question around this before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765165/nhibernate-update-reference/1765464#1765464. The only other option is to fiddle with the ID and that goes against NHibernate best practices that suggest that the Id should be readonly.

Comment: @Michael Gattuso: Thanks for filling me in.